# Only fill 60 percent star using css width

Tags: html, css, unicode

When I am try `style=width:60%` to `.rating` class, gold color should be fill up only 3 stars and rest of stars should be blank but it does not work. Please help me what is my mistake ?

My html code:

```
<div class="star">
   <div class="rating" style="width:60%">
      <span>&#9734;</span>
      <span>&#9734;</span>
      <span>&#9734;</span>
      <span>&#9734;</span>
      <span>&#9734;</span> 
   </div>
</div>
```

My css code:

```
.star{ width:200px; position: relative;color: #bdbdbd;}

.rating span
 {   
    font-size:30px;
    margin-left:-4px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
 }

.rating  span:before { 
 content:"\2605";
 position: absolute;
 color:gold;
 }
```

CHECK [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/fkmmzdc6)

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fkmmzdc6/

Comment: when I apply style=width:60%  width to .rating class only fill 3 star not all and when I apply style=width:100% then fill all star with color:gold but it does not work

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is what I have previously used. This works quite nicely - you can even have a fraction of a star filled out...

https://jsfiddle.net/4qqspqxh/

```css
.ratings {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #b1b1b1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.full-stars{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fde16d;
}

.empty-stars:before,
.full-stars:before {
  content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605";
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.empty-stars:before {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #848484;
}

.full-stars:before {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px orange;
}

/* Webkit-text-stroke is not supported on firefox or IE */
/* Firefox */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .full-stars{
    color: #ECBE24;
  }
}
/* IE */
<!--[if IE]>
  .full-stars{
    color: #ECBE24;
  }
<![endif]-->
```

```html
<div class="ratings">
  <div class="empty-stars"></div>
  <div class="full-stars" style="width:70%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great! One cosmetic suggestion: you could use `\2605` as content for `.empty-stars:before` and in my opinion it would look even better. Thank you for such an elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap your gray and gold starts. Each star is 30px, so the total size is 150px, not 200px. To prevent the starts from wrapping to the next line, use `overflow: hidden;`. Try this:

```css
.star{ width:150px; position: relative;color: #bdbdbd;}

.rating {
  width:60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.rating span{
  font-size:30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: gold;
}

.rating span:before { 
  content:"\2606\2606\2606\2606\2606";
  position: absolute;
  color: #bdbdbd;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="star">
   <div class="rating">
      <span>&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Note: the width of each star is 30px in IE, so the total width is 150px. However, in Chrome the width of the star is 25px, so the total width is 125px. To solve this, so your percentage works across the browsers, you will need to specify the width of each star using `display: inner-block; width: 30px;`.

Comment: It looks clumsy with the margin-left:4px in the :before. Is that by design? To my eyes it looks better without this property.

Comment: @MrLister It depends on the browser that you're using. In IE, it is good. If I remove it, it looks good in Chrome but not in IE. The reason is that there is a space between the stars and the OP fixed them with `margin-left: -4px;`, but that's not a good fix because the space size is different from browser to another. I've removed the space so now it looks the same in all browsers.