# How to use two contents in css over each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a wordpress site and have star rating in the website.
I use css along with javascript to implement this.Below is the code for that.

**HTML PART**

```
<div class="rating1"></div>
```

**STYLE PART**

```
<style>
    .rating1::before {
        content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605"
    }
    .rating1 {
        font-size: 48px;
        color: #ffa500;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
<style>
```

**SCRIPT PART**

```
<script>
   function rating1(stars1) {
      var ratingfill1 = stars1;
      var rating_integer1 = Math.floor(ratingfill1);
      var rating_decimal1 = ratingfill1 % 1;
      var rating_dec_trimmed1 = rating_decimal1.toFixed(1);
      if ((rating_dec_trimmed1 == 0.1) || (rating_dec_trimmed1 == 0.2) ||
         (rating_dec_trimmed1 == 0.3) || (rating_dec_trimmed1 == 0.4)) {
         document.getElementById("star1s" + getstarid).style.width =
            ((40 * rating_integer1) + 18) + 'px';
      }
      if ((rating_dec_trimmed1 == 0.6) || (rating_dec_trimmed1 == 0.7) ||
         (rating_dec_trimmed1 == 0.8) || (rating_dec_trimmed1 == 0.9)) {
         document.getElementById("star1s" + getstarid).style.width =
            ((40 * rating_integer1) + 28) + 'px';
      }
      if (rating_dec_trimmed1 == 0.5) {
         document.getElementById("star1s" + getstarid).style.width =
            ((40 * rating_integer1) + 20) + 'px';
      }
      if (rating_dec_trimmed1 == 0) {
         document.getElementById("star1s" + getstarid).style.width =
            (40 * rating_integer1) + 'px';
      }
   }
</script>
```

I am using a javascript function to display stars(even fractional values can be displayed)This function(rating1()) changed the length of star content according to value of star1 given to the function.

[image: Sample screenshot if star1 value is 4.5]

What i want to accomplish is add star without fill('\2606') exactly below the star with fill('\2605') to accomplish something like this.[image: Scrrenshot of what i want to accomplish]

Comment: I think the first thing you need to do is to format your code so it's easier for people to read.

Comment: Can we see the implementation of rating1()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing your starts like this might make things easier for you. It is two sets of stars with grey stars and yellow stars absolute position on top. The yellows stars wrapper has`overflow:hidden;` so you can set it's percentage width to define how many yellow stars you want to show.

```css
.rating::before, .rating-wrapper::before {
  content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605"
}
.rating-wrapper {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.rating {
  color: #ffa500;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;left:0;right:0;
  width:90%; /* Adjust this width to define how many stars to show */
  height:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="rating-wrapper"><div class="rating"></div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.Your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to drive the appearance of the stars mainly via the icons content, for style reasons, you could do something like this:

```css
body {
    background: gold
}
.icons::before, .icons::after {
    font-size: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.icons::before{
    content: "\2606\2606\2606\2606\2606";
}
.icons::after {
    content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605";
    width: 93px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons"> </div>
```

BTW, this question is very, very similar to [the one posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858426/only-fill-60-percent-star-using-css-width), which I bumped into while writing my answer.

The only reason I leave this, is in case you are only interested in achieving the result via [CSS Pseudo-Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) of a same html element.

Comment: Thanks,your answer is also correct,but i am using WizardCoder's answer in my code.Is it possible to put correct tick in multple answers?

Comment: I don't think you can mark multiple answers as correct (I'm still a noob here on SO) but no worries; I posted this just in case you were strictly after using two different set of icons (ie. you wanted "empty", transparent stars in the background). Since @WizardCoder's answer was correct and serving your need, it makes sense you ticked that one. All good :)