# How to replace star image with star font?

Tags: php, html, css

Please help to replace the star image with the star font (content: '\2605') in the rating.

DataLife Engine (DLE) CMS rating.
It's not the first time I've tried to change it, but it doesn't work. A few lines of code... but I don't understand how and where to properly place :before and content: '\2605'

```css
body {
  background: #181818;
}
/*-- Start rating stars --*/
.unit-rating {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 170px;
        height: 17px;
        position: relative;
        background: url("data:image/png;base64,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") repeat-x;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .unit-rating li {
        text-indent: -90000px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        float: left
    }
    
    .unit-rating li a {
        display: block;
        width: 17px;
        height: 17px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-indent: -9000px;
        z-index: 17;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0
    }
    
    .unit-rating li a:hover {
        background: url("data:image/png;base64,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") 0 -17px;
        z-index: 2;
        left: 0
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r1-unit {
        left: 0
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r1-unit:hover {
        width: 17px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r2-unit {
        left: 17px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r2-unit:hover {
        width: 34px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r3-unit {
        left: 34px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r3-unit:hover {
        width: 51px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r4-unit {
        left: 51px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r4-unit:hover {
        width: 68px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r5-unit {
        left: 68px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r5-unit:hover {
        width: 85px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r6-unit {
        left: 85px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r6-unit:hover {
        width: 102px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r7-unit {
        left: 102px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r7-unit:hover {
        width: 119px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r8-unit {
        left: 119px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r8-unit:hover {
        width: 136px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r9-unit {
        left: 136px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r9-unit:hover {
        width: 153px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r10-unit {
        left: 153px
    }
    
    .unit-rating a.r10-unit:hover {
        width: 170px
    }
    
    .unit-rating li.current-rating {
        background: url("data:image/png;base64,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") 0 -34px;
        position: absolute;
        height: 17px;
        display: block;
        text-indent: -9000px;
        z-index: 1
    }
```

```html
<div id='ratig-layer-{$id}'>
    <div class="rating">
        <ul class="unit-rating">
        <li class="current-rating" style="width:76.7%;">{$rating}</li>
        <li><a data-link="rating/" title="1" class="r1-unit" onclick="doRate('1', '{$id}'); return false;">1</a></li>
        <li><a data-link="rating/" title="2" class="r2-unit" onclick="doRate('2', '{$id}'); return false;">2</a></li>
        <li><a data-link="rating/" title="3" class="r3-unit" onclick="doRate('3', '{$id}'); return false;">3</a></li>
        <li><a data-link="rating/" title="4" class="r4-unit" onclick="doRate('4', '{$id}'); return false;">4</a></li>
        <li><a data-link="rating/" title="5" class="r5-unit" onclick="doRate('5', '{$id}'); return false;">5</a></li>
        <li><a data-link="rating/" title="6" class="r6-unit" onclick="doRate('6', '{$id}'); return false;">6</a></li>
        <li><a data-link="rating/" title="7" class="r7-unit" onclick="doRate('7', '{$id}'); return false;">7</a></li>
        <li><a data-link="rating/" title="8" class="r8-unit" onclick="doRate('8', '{$id}'); return false;">8</a></li>
        <li><a data-link="rating/" title="9" class="r9-unit" onclick="doRate('9', '{$id}'); return false;">9</a></li>
        <li><a data-link="rating/" title="10" class="r10-unit" onclick="doRate('10', '{$id}'); return false;">10</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/cool4ik/pen/mdxpbzV

updated:
Article rating is active and changing. The stars are not fully colored, the number is in %, the output of the variable is in style="width:**{$rating}**%;" currently labeled as: style="width:**76.7**%;".

Comment: Have you searched for pre-existing pages on Stack Overflow that fill stars by a percentage? https://stackoverflow.com/q/33858426/2943403

Answer (score 0):

Taken from http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/zLrd0p5s/, and slightly improved.

Explanation: When hovering the container all the stars change *except* the stars that are *after* `~` the one hovered.

```css
#rating_bar {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

#rating_bar>li:before {
  content: '☆';
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 3em;
  float: left;
}

#rating_bar>li.active:before {
  content: '★';
  color: blue;
}

#rating_bar:hover>li:before {
  content: '★';
  color: blue;
}

#rating_bar>li:hover~li:before {
  content: '☆';
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="rating_bar">
  <li id="rate_1" class="active"></li>
  <li id="rate_2" class="active"></li>
  <li id="rate_3" class="active"></li>
  <li id="rate_4"></li>
  <li id="rate_5"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I can't change 'span' to 'li', also consider 'a' links and 'current rating' style which draws stars as a percentage (

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. The rating for articles is active and changing. Therefore, the script passed the width of the color of the stars in the code through a variable:
<li class="current-rating" style="width:{$rating}%;">{$rating}</li>
You can somehow assign class="active" to one star and paint over all the previous ones, so that in the end there is a % rating, for example, for a rating of 7.55?
In your example, everything is quite transparent, but this does not quite adapt to the code that I gave above.

Comment: You would need to have 10 stars and put `active` on the first 8.